# One-line output operator for a binary tree

Tags: c++, output, binary-tree

I wrote a simple binary tree class in C++ and want to add an output operator to it. My first attempt was:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Tree& tree) {
    out << tree.myData;
    if (tree.myLeft)
        out << "(" << (*tree.myLeft)  << ")";
    if (tree.myRight)
        out << "[" << (*tree.myRight)  << "]";
    return out;
}
```

(where myLeft and myRight are pointers to left and right child of the current tree, respectively). This works correctly, however, it is not sufficiently cool, since it spans several lines and requires to write "out << " several times.

As an attempt to create a one-line operator, I wrote this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Tree& tree) {
    return (out << tree.myData
        << "(" << (tree.myLeft? *tree.myLeft: "")  << ")"
        << "[" << (tree.myRight? *tree.myRight: "") << "]");
}
```

But, this generates an error:

> incompatible operand types ('Tree' and 'const char [1]')

So I tried this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Tree& tree) {
    return (&tree?
        out << tree.myData
            << "(" << *(tree.myLeft)  << ")"
            << "[" << *(tree.myRight) << "]":
        out);
}
```

This works on my computer, but generates a warning implying that this is undefined behavior:

> Reference cannot be bound to dereferenced null pointer in well-defined C++ code; pointer may be assumed to always convert to true [-Wundefined-bool-conversion]

QUESTION: Is there a way to write this output operator in a simple single statement?

Comment: `This works correctly, however, it is not sufficiently cool, since it spans several lines and requires to write "out << " several times.` Why does this matter? You only write the function once and then simply just have to do `out << Tree;` in your actual code.

Comment: My question for you: Why do you want to do such a thing?  Your first code block is clear, concise, very easy to maintain, and requires almost no brain power to understand. That is the kind of code you should be writing by default.

Comment: @NathanOliver It is not code for production - it is for learning. Thanks to my attempt to write a one-liner, I already learned two new things about C++:  that the ternary operator requires compatible data types, and that dereferencing a null pointer is defined as undefined behavior. Both were very surprising for me. Now, I am curious whether c++ has another surprise with which this puzzle can be solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple and elegant solution is to redesign your tree to work without null pointers. Instead, replace current uses of null pointers with pointers to a sentinel tree node which has behaviour consistent with an empty tree.

Then you can rewrite your output stream operator as follows:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Tree& tree) {
    if (&tree == &Tree::NULL_TREE_SENTINEL) return out;
    return out << tree.myData
        << "(" << *tree.myLeft  << ")"
        << "[" << *tree.myRight << "]";
}
```

(This assumes a corresponding static member inside `Tree`, to which the sentinels are pointers, like singletons.)

Alternatively, the sentinel tree node could be an instance of a subclass of `Tree` with this behaviour. This is sometimes known as the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern). However, it requires dynamic dispatch (i.e. runtime polymorphism via virtual member functions) to work.

---

Apart from this you don’t quite diagnose the problem with your second code correctly:

> This works on my computer

It *appears* to work but doesn’t actually. I don’t know under what exact circumstances that code will actually do something nasty. But just to be clear, your code is illegal due to the sub-expressions `*(tree.myLeft)` and `*(tree.myRight)`: these expressions are dereferencing null pointers, and this is never legal. The warning message you’re receiving about the `&tree` test is merely a *symptom* of that prior error.

Comment: Wonderful idea. But it returned an error "error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const Tree' and 'Tree')".   The problem was solved when I compared pointers:   "if (&tree == &Tree::NULL_TREE_SENTINEL)... "
"

Comment: Regarding the second comment: indeed it took me some time to realize that this is illegal. I always thought that a reference is just a syntactic sugar for a pointer, and that "&*p" is equivalent to "p". Now I see that "&*p" is not equivalent to "p" when p is null.